# Recursively apply ets/auto.arima to daily data of sequentially larger length

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a number of time series data with daily observations (approximately 2 months of data) used for back testing. The system should automatically update the model at the end of each day, when new daily data becomes available, making forecasts for the next 7 days.

I tried to see how the ets method would look like, so I start with data for a full week (days 1:7) and build a model predicting the next 7 days (8:15), then use days 1:8, predict days 9:16 and so on.

I have a loop like this:

`for (t in 7:49) {
  ts_data <- ts(data[1:t], frequency=7)
  fit <- ets(ts_data)
  plot(forecast(fit,7))
}`

Once the for loop reaches the second repetition, I get an error at ets:

Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:length(x)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2

So is there a rule for setting K in the fourier function? Apparently, I cannot set this completely manually as the data changes and there are a lot of time series datasets to predict. It is the first time I am working on time series model, so apologies if this is a naive question.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841142/forecast-throws-error-k-must-be-not-be-greater-than-period-2) but apparently even if t=14 (multiple of 7), I still get the same error, and generally I do not understand why I would need to have exact multiples of the frequency (weekly here).

Note: I have tried to remove the frequency=7 and ets works fine but it does not get any seasonality patterns, in contrast to when the frequency=7 where I get much better results.

Comment: Update to v6.2 of the forecast package.

Comment: Prof. Hyndman, I have read your book, slides, lectures and posts here and I would just like to say a huge thanks, I wish more academics did the same in their area. I will update it now